# Trouble Installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble installing crypt-ruby 3.0.1 on my mac. Does anyone now what the cause of this maybe? Below is the following output error.

```
Dorians-MacBook-Pro:rentsnap_webapp dorianflowers$ gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bcrypt-ruby:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

      /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150722-8311-1gpgksu.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
In file included from /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:29,
             from /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33,
             from bcrypt_ext.c:1:
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/defines.h:26:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/defines.h:28:24: error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/defines.h:31:23: error: sys/stat.h: No such file or directory
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/defines.h:34:21: error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/defines.h:45:21: error: string.h: No such file or directory
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/defines.h:48:22: error: strings.h: No such file or directory
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/defines.h:51:23: error: inttypes.h: No such file or directory
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/defines.h:54:21: error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/defines.h:57:21: error: unistd.h: No such file or directory
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/defines.h:61:25: error: sys/select.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/defines.h:68,
                 from /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:29,
                 from /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from bcrypt_ext.c:1:
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/missing.h:23:45: error: math.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:184,
                 from /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from bcrypt_ext.c:1:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/include/limits.h:15:25: error: limits.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:35,
                 from /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1694,
                 from /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from bcrypt_ext.c:1:
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/st.h:139: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint32_t’
In file included from /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1694,
                 from /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from bcrypt_ext.c:1:
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:348: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:440: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘fd_set’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:440: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘fd_set’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:440: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘fd_set’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:440: warning: ‘struct timeval’ declared inside parameter list
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:440: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:441: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:441: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:441: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘rb_fdset_t’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:441: warning: ‘struct timeval’ declared inside parameter list
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:442: warning: ‘struct timeval’ declared inside parameter list
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:545: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘mode_t’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:624: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘pid_t’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:638: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_fork’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:639: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_fork_err’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:641: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_waitpid’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:642: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘pid’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:643: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_spawn’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:644: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rb_spawn_err’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:646: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘pid’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:755: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘uint32_t’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:882: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘long’
/Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/intern.h:883: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘long’
bcrypt_ext.c: In function ‘bc_salt’:
bcrypt_ext.c:46: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: What are the contents of /Users/dorianflowers/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/gem_make.out ?

Comment: Also, the compiler on osx versions have changed significantly over the past few releases, can you try installing the most current version of bcrypt? You might be able to `bundle update bcrypt` to bypass the problem entirely.

Comment: The contents are what are seen in the body of the question. I also tried running 'bundle update bcrypt' and it responded with 'Could not find gem 'crypt'.'

Comment: Do you have Xcode and command line tools updated on your Mac? If not then make sure those are up to date.

Comment: Possible info: https://petros.blog/2020/10/02/fixing-the-implicit-declaration-of-function-error-when-installing-ruby-gems/

Answer (score 1):

[According to this article](https://petros.blog/2020/10/02/fixing-the-implicit-declaration-of-function-error-when-installing-ruby-gems/), it seems to be caused by an update to xcode tools on mac, to fix this you need to add a flag to ignore that error like it used to do before.

For example in my case this worked:

```sh
gem install bcrypt-ruby:3.0.1 -- --build-flags --with-cflags="-Wno-error=implicit-function-declaration"
```

Comment: You have a different issue. This six year old question was not asked because of an issue that first appeared in macOS one year ago. While you may have an issue with installing bcrypt 3.0.1 and while you may have resolved it with that step, the cause and the error messages that you received are completely different from OP. (and for OP, the **only** solution is to install the missing header files, files that you already had installed)

Comment: This answer has helped me with the Mac OS M1 chip issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

These errors all indicate that there is no compiler on your computer:

```
error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
error: sys/stat.h: No such file or directory
error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
error: string.h: No such file or directory
error: strings.h: No such file or directory
error: inttypes.h: No such file or directory
error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
error: unistd.h: No such file or directory
error: sys/select.h: No such file or directory
```

On macOS, the easiest way to resolve this is to install the Xcode command line tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

The Xcode command line tools include all the above libraries and the compilers needed to build bcrypt-ruby. (and most other gems)

Comment: Running that gives me `error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates` on macOS 11.5.2 build 20G95